# How can I make a function that takes two lists as args and returns true if the first list exists in the second?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have to write this in sml/nj
I made a try and this is what I did:

I want the all function to return a positive number when I run the function but for example when I give `[1,2,3] [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]` it 
returns nonexhaustive match failure.
What is wrong with the function and what can I do to see if the elements
of the first list exist in the second?

```
fun elem num [] = false
  | elem num (x::xs) = if num = x then true else elem num xs

fun all [] [] =
  let
    fun qwe [] [] acc = acc
      | qwe (x::xs) (z::zs) acc = if elem x (z::zs) then qwe xs (z::zs) (1+acc) else qwe xs (z::zs) acc
  in
    qwe [] [] 0
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition of `all`, you seem to be slipping into thinking of `[]` as being a generic list rather than an empty list.

The only pattern that actually appears in your definition of `all` is `[] []` (two empty lists). That is most emphatically a case of nonexhaustive matching.

Since the helper function `qwe` does the actual work, there really isn't any point in having pattern-matching on `all` itself. The overall form of `all` could be:

```
fun all xs ys =
  let
    fun qwe = (*insert definition*)
  in
    qwe xs ys 0
  end;
```

(using `zs` rather than `ys` here looks a bit awkward)

The definition of `que` should have 2-4 patterns. A 4-pattern definition (required for some functions which operate on two lists would be):

```
fun qwe [] [] acc = (*insert def*)
  | qwe [] (y::ys) acc = (*insert def*)
  | qwe (x::xs) [] acc = (*insert def*)
  | qwe (x::xs) (y::ys) acc = (*insert def*)
```

This last gives 4 cases, one for each Boolean combination of the first list and the second list being empty. Sometimes you don't need to write separate code for each of those. For example,

```
fun qwe [] [] acc = (*insert def*)
  | qwe [] ys acc = (*insert def*)
  | qwe (x::xs) ys acc = (*insert def*)
```

combines the 3rd and 4th case into a single case.

If you look at your actual definition of `elem`, you realize that *it* handles the case of empty `ys` nicely, so in your definition of `qwe`, you can really just have two patterns based on what `xs` is doing:

```
fun qwe [] ys acc = (*insert def*)
  | qwe (x::xs) ys acc = (*insert def*)
```

Since `ys` can match both empty and nonempty lists, the above template is exhaustive.

With the appropriate definitions (which you essentially already have) for the above two cases of `que`, your function `all` will work:

```
- all [1,2,3] [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1];
val it = 3 : int
```